# Prove that in an abelian Group $G$, if elements $a$ and $b$ have finite order, then so does $ab$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So if $a$ has order $m$ and $b$ has order $n$, do I need to find a positive integer $k$ such that $(ab)^k=e)$?

I am not sure how to proceed forward

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is exactly what you need to do. Now, you know that $a^m=e$ and that $b^n=e$. You also know that $ab=ba$. Can you compute $(ab)^m$ or $(ab)^n$? do you now have an idea of how to choose $k$?

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $(ab)^{nm}=(a^m)^n(b^n)^m=e$.